# Is the shell created by `bash -i -c <command>` interactive?

Tags: bash

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276611/674

> When `bash` is run with `-c`, it is considered a non-interactive
>   shell, and it does not read `~/.bashrc`, unless is `-i` specified. 
>   So,
>
> ```
> $ type cp
> cp is aliased to ‘cp -i’          # Defined in  ~/.bashrc
>
> $ cp .file1 file2
> cp: overwrite ‘file2’? n
>
> $ bash -c "cp .file1 file2"
>                                   # Existing file is overwritten without confirmation!
> $ bash -c -i "cp .file1 file2"
> cp: overwrite ‘file2’? n
> ```

Is the shell created by `bash -i -c <command>` interactive or non-interactive?

Such a shell doesn't accept a command from stdin, does it? So it is not interactive, is it?

Such a shell reads `~/.bashrc`, so it can't be non-interactive, can it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use **$-**

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f%20%22Bash%20Reference%20Manual%22:):

> To determine within a startup script whether or not Bash is running
>   interactively, test the value of the ‘-’ special parameter. It
>   contains i when the shell is interactive.

For this example,

```
$ bash -c 'echo $-'      # This is a non-interactive shell
hBc

$ bash -i -c 'echo $-'   # This is an interactive shell
himBHc
```

Comment: Thanks. For `bash -i -c`, if it is an interactive shell, can it accept a command from stdin?

Comment: @Tim It can accept a command from stdin even if it is a non-interactive shell, because both types of shell started with `bash -c` **are still attached to the current terminal**. Consider this simple "command interpreter", which will execute the command `ls` from stdin despite running as a non-interactive shell: `echo ls | bash -c 'read p; eval "$p"'`

Comment: How do you define if a shell is interactive or non-interactive? I thought that accepting a command from stdin is the defining characteristic.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277145/674, and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43389/674

Comment: @Tim The official definition is [this one](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f.html#What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f). See also [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior). "Interactive" vs. "non-interactive" primarily refers to the shell's behavior, not where it gets its input from.

Comment: I really think that one isn't a definition in terms of what interactive means, but enumeration of all the ways to invoke an interactive shell.

Comment: The example `echo ls | bash -c 'read p; eval "$p"'` accepts input to command `read` from stdin, and it doesn't accept a command from stdin.