# Can you enumerate all the ways to start an interactive shell?

Tags: bash, interactive

Bash manual says:

> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments, **unless -s is specified,**
>   without specifying the -c option, and whose input and output are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.

I was wondering which "unless -s is specified" applies to:

- "without non-option arguments", or
- "without specifying the -c option"?

Can you rephrase the quote more clearly to enumerate all the ways to start an interactive shell? (I am only clear that I can start one by `-i` alone, but not sure about the other way(s) which the quote describes.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“unless `-s` is specified” qualifies “without non-option arguments”. The synopsis for `bash` is

```
bash [options] [command_string | file]
```

Non-option arguments are `command_string` or `file`. If you specify either of these, the resulting shell isn’t interactive, unless you specify `-s`, without specifying `-c`. `-s` causes the arguments to be assigned to the positional parameters instead of being interpreted:

```
bash -s arg1 arg2
```

opens an interactive shell, and

```
echo $*
```

outputs

```
arg1 arg2
```

So you can open an interactive Bash shell using either of the following:

1. ensure the standard input and output are connected to a terminal and specify no non-option arguments;
2. ensure the standard input and output are connected to a terminal and specify `-s` with any arguments apart from `-c`;
3. specify `-i`.

If you specify both `-c` and `-s`, `-c` takes precedence (it’s processed earlier). The resulting shell is non-interactive and processes the given command.

Comment: Thanks. What kind of shell is it, if the standard input and output are connected to a terminal and "specify both -s and -c"?

Comment: One might do well to refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277312/ from 2016 at this point.

Comment: Thanks. Still confused. In "without non-option arguments, unless -s is specified, without specifying the -c option", (1)  which is the "unless" clause: "unless -s is specified", or "unless -s is specified, without specifying the -c option"? (2) What does "non-option argument" mean? If an option expects an argument following it, is an argument following it a non-option argument? For example, is `"echo hello"` in `bash -c "echo hello"` a nonoption argument?

Comment: (cont) (2) In `bash -c "echo hello"`, if I am correct, `"echo hello"` is called an option argument, so there is no nonoption argument and it fits the first bullet point in your reply. But the shell it created isn't interactive.